# What type of report?

Tags: c#, reporting

My company has written 40 reports for our own use in a third-party application.  We'd like to move away from the application and use these reports in our own host application.  I'd like to use the reports without rewriting all of them. I'm trying to determine if these reports are written for a control we can somehow obtain.  The reports look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Reports>
  <Report version="4.6.20132.54638">
    <Name>Settlement Detail Batch</Name>
    <ReportInfo />
    <DataSource>
      <DataProvider>0</DataProvider>
    </DataSource>
    <Layout>
      <Width>9450</Width>
      <MarginTop>400</MarginTop>
      <MarginBottom>1080</MarginBottom>
      <Orientation>1</Orientation>
      <PaperSize>1</PaperSize>
    </Layout>
    <Font>
      <Name>Times New Roman</Name>
      <Size>9</Size>
    </Font>
    <CompatibilityOptions />
    <Groups>
      <Group>
      </Group>
    </Groups>
    <Sections>
      <Section>
      </Section>
...
```

How do I determine if this control is available?

Thanks
T.

Comment: That looks like an SSRS report, I am not sure though.

Comment: How are the reports stored? Since your company wrote the reports, you should be able to give us atleast the name of the previously used reporting software

Comment: It's an application called Morphis.  The actual report XML is stored in their database.  They provide a report viewer and report authoring tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling (made search for "4.6.20132.54638") version number leads to C1 Reports. So reports probably are made with Component One Reporting tools. You can try to [download C1 Reporting tools](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ReportsWinForms/), then use Report Designer to import report from your xml file and you see if they are made with these tools.

Comment: Crap.. I think you're right.  I searched for 4.6.20132 and only got 5 vague results.  (I thought using the minor version number would narrow the search.)